# Upload iPhone video clips to blog via native WP app

Tags: uploads, attachments, videos, iphone, video-player

I'm using the WordPress iPhone app, and when I upload video clips to a blog they show up in some browsers and in others not. I'm using a HTML5 video markup as a container for the clips. While mpeg-4 doesn't work in Firefox and Opera I would really expect the clips to work in Apple's own browser Safari, which they don't. The only browser I can currently view these clips in is Chrome.

Here's my markup for the uploaded clips:

```
<video width="960" height="540" src="http://path/to/clip/1.mov" type="video/quicktime" controls>Your browser can't play this video.</video>
```

It seems that .mov files are harder to interpret for Safari than it's mp4 counterpart. Could it be that Safari needs the clips to be in the latter format? If it does, what approach would you recommend converting these files when uploading a video clip?
Any directions regarding this issue are much appreciated.